# Why does The special menu items module break the bootstrap dropdown?

Tags: javascript, theming

Hi Guys this is my issue on my parent menu item i am using the`<nolink>`shortcode to leave the link blank however in my tree i have 3 items underneath it.

If i add `<nolink>` the menu item becomes wrapped in a span tag with no link and the dropdown does not work. if i give the parent a link the dropdown works but only if i select the parent first.

Is this css or a js issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: About the `<span>` with `<nolink>` see [Menu Tricks with Drupal, Bootstrap, and Special Menu Items](http://areatype.com/blog/menu-tricks-drupal-bootstrap-special-menu-items). About the click instead of hover see [Bootstrap 3 dropdown hover support](https://www.drupal.org/node/2248469), marked as fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It's because bootstrap is expecting an anchor tag and by default Special Menu Items provides a span tag.

Go to admin/config/system/special_menu_items and specify an anchor tag as shown below:

[image]